# Use of Ubuntu hosting a commercial web aplication

Tags: server

I wanted to ask if a paid license must be acquired or any payment made when Ubuntu is used on a virtual server and a web application for commercial purposes is hosted on this server (built with Javascript, Php and Postgresql) to which several users would connect through their browsers with username and password. I ask this because I know that Ubuntu has a GPL license, however I have also read that it has other licenses (from third parties) of which I am unaware and I do not know for which components or in what circumstances it applies. Grettings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oversimplified:

- Ubuntu is free to use for any commercial and non-commercial purposes. Ubuntu is offered with no warranty.

  Some users pay for optional additional support services. None pay for a "commercial use" license -- that does not exist.
- The GPL and other licenses apply to redistribution of Ubuntu and about access to any changes that you make to the software.

  You cannot change Open Source software, built upon the contributions of many thousands of contributors, into your own Proprietary software.

  You cannot use the Ubuntu name without permission.

For a detailed explanation of your rights and responsibilities when your organization uses Ubuntu, consult a lawyer in your country.

If your organization profits from the use of Ubuntu, consider a small contribution of time or effort to help improve it.

Comment: It was a precise and clear explanation.